# "New" render redirects to unexpected URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My app has a page allowing users to send me an email through a form (without my address being published). It's associated with an Email controller and is the #new action, which I rerouted to '/contact'.

The weird thing, is if the email doesn't send off for any reason (the user left a field blank or failed the math captcha I put in), when the controller renders "new" again, the url becomes '/emails'. I can't figure this one out at all. Some relevant code:

```
#emails_controller.rb

require 'math_captcha'

class EmailsController < ApplicationController

    def new
    @captcha = MathCaptcha.new
    @email = Email.new
  end

    def create
    @captcha = MathCaptcha.decrypt(params[:captcha_secret])
    @email = Email.new(params[:email])

    unless @captcha.correct?(params[:captcha]) || params[:captcha] == "21261"
        flash.now[:error] = "Please make sure you answered the math question correctly."
        render :new
    else
      if @email.save
        Contact.contact_message(@email).deliver
        flash[:success] = "Your email has sent! I'll try to get back to you shortly."
        redirect_to root_path
      else
        flash.now[:error] = "Please correct the highlighted errors and try again."
        render :new
      end
    end

    end

end
```

And:

```
#routes.rb

resources :users, :posts, :sessions, :emails

#...

match '/contact', to: 'emails#new', as: 'contact'
```

The same problem was there before I added "as contact" in an attempt to fix it. Any ideas?

EDIT -- per garbage collection's request (sorry for the delay; haven't been near my computer for a bit), here's the dev log for navigating to /contact and submitting an unsuccessful email attempt (which refreshes and changes the URL to /emails):

```
Started GET "/contact" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:40 -1000
Processing by EmailsController#new as HTML
  Rendered emails/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 20ms (Views: 19.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:40 -1000
Served asset /application.css - 304 Not Modified (2ms)


Started GET "/assets/custom.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:40 -1000
Served asset /custom.css - 304 Not Modified (2ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:40 -1000
Served asset /jquery_ujs.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/angular.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:40 -1000
Served asset /angular.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/pygments.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:40 -1000
Served asset /pygments.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:40 -1000
Served asset /jquery.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:40 -1000
Served asset /bootstrap-transition.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-affix.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:40 -1000
Served asset /bootstrap-affix.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:40 -1000
Served asset /bootstrap-alert.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-button.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:40 -1000
Served asset /bootstrap-button.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:40 -1000
Served asset /bootstrap-carousel.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:40 -1000
Served asset /bootstrap-collapse.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:40 -1000
Served asset /bootstrap-modal.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:40 -1000
Served asset /bootstrap-dropdown.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-scrollspy.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:40 -1000
Served asset /bootstrap-scrollspy.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:40 -1000
Served asset /bootstrap-popover.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:40 -1000
Served asset /bootstrap.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:40 -1000
Served asset /bootstrap-tab.js - 304 Not Modified (46ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-typeahead.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:40 -1000
Served asset /bootstrap-typeahead.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:40 -1000
Served asset /bootstrap-tooltip.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/emails.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:40 -1000
Served asset /emails.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/posts.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:40 -1000
Served asset /posts.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/expand.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:40 -1000
Served asset /expand.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/sessions.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:40 -1000
Served asset /sessions.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/users.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:40 -1000
Served asset /users.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/statics.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:40 -1000
Served asset /statics.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:40 -1000
Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/posts.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:41 -1000
Processing by PostsController#index as JSON
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 2]]
  [1m[35mPost Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" 
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 3.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)


Started GET "/assets/sign_out.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:41 -1000
Served asset /sign_out.png - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started POST "/emails" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:44 -1000
Processing by EmailsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"hjd4q/tvu6IhqpdC7rPMkS21s0GTiqILqOA8ZkLKXsk=", "email"=>{"name"=>"", "address"=>"", "subject"=>"", "content"=>""}, "captcha_secret"=>"xmuKN1l8HVyPlbsfymoVWTieuFYYO3qcXoUUawh8vyw=\r\n", "captcha"=>"", "commit"=>"Send"}
  Rendered emails/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 2]]
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 25ms (Views: 22.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:44 -1000
Served asset /application.css - 304 Not Modified (2ms)


Started GET "/assets/pygments.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:44 -1000
Served asset /pygments.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:44 -1000
Served asset /bootstrap-transition.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:44 -1000
Served asset /jquery_ujs.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/angular.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:44 -1000
Served asset /angular.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/custom.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:44 -1000
Served asset /custom.css - 304 Not Modified (1ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:44 -1000
Served asset /jquery.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-affix.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:44 -1000
Served asset /bootstrap-affix.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-button.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:44 -1000
Served asset /bootstrap-button.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:44 -1000
Served asset /bootstrap-alert.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:44 -1000
Served asset /bootstrap-carousel.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:44 -1000
Served asset /bootstrap-modal.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:44 -1000
Served asset /bootstrap-collapse.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:44 -1000
Served asset /bootstrap-dropdown.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-scrollspy.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:44 -1000
Served asset /bootstrap-scrollspy.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:44 -1000
Served asset /bootstrap-tooltip.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:44 -1000
Served asset /bootstrap-tab.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-typeahead.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:44 -1000
Served asset /bootstrap-typeahead.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:44 -1000
Served asset /bootstrap.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:44 -1000
Served asset /bootstrap-popover.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/expand.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:44 -1000
Served asset /expand.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/emails.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:44 -1000
Served asset /emails.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/posts.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:44 -1000
Served asset /posts.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/users.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:44 -1000
Served asset /users.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:44 -1000
Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (1ms)


Started GET "/assets/sessions.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:44 -1000
Served asset /sessions.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/statics.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:44 -1000
Served asset /statics.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/posts.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:44 -1000
Processing by PostsController#index as JSON
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  [1m[36mPost Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" [0m
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 2.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/assets/sign_out.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-16 08:46:44 -1000
Served asset /sign_out.png - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
```

Comment: Can you share the server log for when creating email fails?

Answer (score 1):

It's expected to show '/emails' in the address bar since you just POST'ed to that url.  If you really want to show '/contact', you should set up a route for POST like:

get '/contact', to: 'emails#new'
post '/contact', to: 'emails#create'

Maybe there's another, more concise way to do it, but this should work.

Comment: Tried it, but the redirect persists.